# $A$ and $B$ be non-empty bounded set of real numbers, give a counter example to the following.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Assume $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$. Find a counter-example to the claim:

$\sup(A \cap B) = \min\{\sup(A), \:\sup(B)\}$

I cant seem to find a counter example to the above claim, can anyone provide
a counter example to this ?

Thanks for reading my post.

Answer (score 3):

$$A= \{1,2,3 \}$$
$$B= \{2,4 \}$$